# how to integrate dictionary for autocomplete with built in app e.g.messaging,contacts in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I want to integrate dictionary feature(predictive text) to built in application such as messaging,contacts .But i don't want to use built in predictive text feature provided by android.
The problem is that i m not able to integrate built in application with my dictionary.

Comment: Cannot  understand your question. You don't want to use built in feature. And at the same time you are integrating it into your app?